# BuildRowsetFromJson not returning anything

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json

I am trying to use the new function in ampscript - **BuildRowsetFromJson**. But I am not getting the expected outcome.

What I am doing in my code

- Calling the public endpoint
- The endpoint returns JSON in the following format

```
    [
    {
    “ID”: “1001”,
    "subjectLine": "testtttt",
    "preheader": "Save on your next order"
    }
    ]
```

Below is the ampscript code that I am using in the email to fetch the **preheader** field from the JSON/ API endpoint using the new function BuildRowsetFromJson

```
<!-- Make API call using ampscript -->
%%[
var @url, @jsonresponse, @rows

set @url = 'ENDPOINT URL’;

set @jsonresponse = HTTPGET(@url, false, 0)

set @rows = BuildRowsetFromJson(@jsonresponse, '$[0].preheader', 1)

]%%

<!-- Output the value of @rows -->
here :%%=v(@rows)=%%
```

Please can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you've got curly quotes in your JSON sample and in your code block.

The new BuildRowsetFromJSON function returns a rowset, which you must interrogate for the specific row and field.

```ampscript
%%[

set @jsonresponse = '[{"ID":"1001","subjectLine": "test", "preheader": "Save on your next order"}]'

set @rows = BuildRowsetFromJson(@jsonresponse, '$.[*]', 1)

set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
set @preheader = field(row(@rows,1),"preheader")

]%%
rowcount: %%=v(@rowCount)=%%
<br>preheader: %%=v(@preheader)=%%
```

Output:

```
rowcount: 1
preheader: Save on your next order
```

Try it for yourself: https://mcsnippets.herokuapp.com/s/nRXTpUEe

Comment: thank you so much! the solution you suggested works